# Primary Interop Assembly (PIA)

Tags: .net, interop, assemblies, .net-remoting

What benefits do you get from using PIA when around .NET remoting? I have been asked this question in an interview and my answer was around COM objects, but someone insisted it has benefits around connectivity when using .NET remoting, I searched the web and I couldn't find any connection between PIA and .NET remoting, is there one?

Comment: There isn't.  PIAs solve a type identity problem with COM interop libraries.  The best way to have shown the interviewer that he's full of beans is by pointing out that PIAs do squat when the remoting happens between different machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the interviewer could have been getting confused with server side automation of office, eg [KB257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). Having Office on a server and automating it via .Net remoting probably caused them problems, thats why they "insisted there is benefits around connectivity when using PIAs".

What @HansPassant said is correct, finders crossed a moderator promotes his comment to an answer.